# Java - how to call a generic instance method

Tags: java, generics

```java
class Connection
{
    private Socket m_socket;
    private ObjectOutputStream m_send;
    private ObjectInputStream m_recv;

    // Methods for initializing socket omitted

    public <Type extends Serializable> Type readObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        return (Type)m_recv.readObject(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Connection conn = new Connection();

        // Doesn't work.
        // error: -> expected
        ServerResponse resp = conn.readObject<ServerResponse>();
    }
}
```

Why I am not able to call readObject with supplied type but instead can call it using only `conn.readObject()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out! It works to me.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Connection {

    private Socket m_socket;
    private ObjectOutputStream m_send;
    private ObjectInputStream m_recv;

    // Methods for initializing socket omitted

    public <Type extends Serializable> Type readObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return (Type)m_recv.readObject();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Connection conn = new Connection();
        ServerResponse resp = conn.readObject();
        // This is a full syntax
        // ServerResponse resp = conn.<ServerResponse>readObject();
    }
}

class ServerResponse implements Serializable {}
```

Comment: Should I prefer full syntax or use the short one?

Comment: No. Short one is absolute fine until you do not have `CompileTimeException`.